# Custom Regex Expression = $ ~ # № \ ; < > % /

Tags: regex

I need to create a regular expression which will match the following characters on input:

```
= $ ~ # № \ ; < > % /
```

I don't have any idea how to combine or setup the regex for this case.

i have something like this

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp(???);
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});
```

need to prevent those symbols from typing

Comment: i have something like this :
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp(???);
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});
need to put regex to prevent those chars from user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var pattern = /^[=$~#№\\;<>%/]*$/
```

And if want letters and numbers as well then try this:

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9=$~#№\\;<>%/]*$/
```

Comment: ur regex works except for backslash. "\"
do u have any idea ?